# Lubuntu with python 2.7.8 and 3.4.2 import rrdtool

Tags: python, rrdtool

due to problems when installing rrdtool on windows i decided to switch to Linux to solve many problems.
I've installed Lubuntu (that has python 2.7.8 installed by default) and python 3.4.2.
Than with packet manager i've installed python-rrdtool.

The problem is: from the terminal when i write "python2" and than "import rrdtool" it works, but when i write "python3" import "rrdtool" it says to me that there are no module. How can i use rrdtool also on python3?
thanks
Paolo

Comment: is rddtool installed? try these `pip install rrdtool` or `easy_install rrdtool` then check

Comment: I think that it is istalled becouse with python2 it works!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately python-rrdtool package from Ubuntu/Debian is a python 2.x package only. So it will work in python 2.7 and not in python 3.4.

If you must use rrdtool in python 3.x then you will have to use some alternative python to rrdtool binding. There are several to choose from if you look at pypi.python.org (which you can then install with pip). I have not used them as they all seem to have low version count and am weary of possible bugs. If someone did try those perhaps they could share their experience...